# How can I create a persistent log of console output from a Node.js app running on Azure Cloud Services?

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure

I have a Node.js app running on Azure Cloud Services. I'm currently using a redirection operator (`>>`) to append the console output to a file, but this file is erased when the role recycles. How can I persist the log through role recycles?

Answer (score 0):

In web and worker roles (PaaS), the D: drive is volatile and will not be there across role reboots. The C: drive is supposed to be durable, so make sure you're writing to the C: drive.

With IaaS VMs, and Azure App Service, the storage is persisted across reboots.